# SSLError: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

Tags: python, ssl, environment-variables, ssl-certificate, anaconda3

I am facing the SSLError, when trying to  scrape websites.

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/'
page = requests.get(url)
content=page.content
print(content)
```

Output:~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    429         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
    430             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
--> 431                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    432             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
    433                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)

SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

there is a workaround that works:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/'
page = requests.get(url=url, verify =False)
content=page.content
print(content)
```

But I would love to settle the issue with my certificates!

I have updated everything including requests, reinstalled my Anaconda3,
checked my certificates with https://www.ssllabs.com - they are ok.

System inf: Windows 10, pip version 20.0.2 ,anaconda3,python 3.7

ANY IDEA on WHAT does THAT DAMN 1076 ERROR particularly refer to and HOW TO FIX it?

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: I think verify False skips ssl, and connects via http. That doesn't seem like a workaround but avoids connecting to HTTPS

Comment: yes that is it the https connection fails - can`t see why, checked my verify- its fine

Comment: I actually looked it up online and found a few links pointing me to github and they have had some bug activity on it. I feel this is a known thing.

Comment: Could be -  anyway I decided to try installing Anaconda 4 - that might solve it.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the 'wonderful' Zscaler installed by global IT as the company policy now requires, I got the certificate from the IT department - strugling to install it to Anaconda3 now posting 
[this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635505/installing-zscaler-certificate-to-anaconda3)

Comment: after your Zscaler root cert is installed in the Windows trust root store, just install either pip-system-certs or python-certifi-win32 from either pypi or conda-forge