# Installing Zscaler Certificate to Anaconda3

Tags: ssl, anaconda, ssl-certificate, zscaler

After the obligatory installation of Zscaler through out the Company my Anaconda started giving me the SSL verification Error while installing modules and using requests to get the urls

Error(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/'some_module'/

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.amazon.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

With Zscaler being turned off it all works great, but the company policy does not allow that.....

I found some bypasses like setting verify to False but it is not what I want.

I would like to install the Zscaler certificate (which was provided to me by our IT department) to Anaconda

Now the problem seems to be that it uses conda’s generic certificates.

```
import ssl
print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())
```

Output :
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='C:\ci\openssl_1581353098519\_h_env\Library/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='C:\ci\openssl_1581353098519\_h_env\Library/certs')

Any idea what could I possibly do to point conda to the Zscaler certificate that I have??

system inf: Windows 10, Anaconda3 -2020.02, Python 3.7

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/non-standard-certs.html ?

Answer (score 10):

What you can do is :

1. Open a browser and go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. Next to the reload page button, you will see a lock (see picture below). click on it
3. Click on : Certificate
4. Click on the tab: Certification Path
5. Select Zscaler Root CA5 and the click on View Certificate button
6. Click on the tab: Details and then click on Copy to file button
7. Export the certificate choosing the base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)
8. Choose a path where to save the file
9. Open Anaconda Prompt
10. conda config --set ssl_verify path_of_the_file_that_you_just_saved

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## background

I had this same issue, but ran into a similar with my work laptop except where Zscaler blocked my curl, git, and anaconda traffic. The temporary fix was to disable ssl verification, but this introduces a number of security vulnerabilities such as man-in-the-middle attacks.

From what I could gather and my limited research, WSL2 doesn't have a automatic way of importing ssl certificates from the system.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5134

## Solution

The long term solution is to get the Zscaler certificate and add it to your shell file. Run the following commands in WSL after getting the certificate and navigating to the directory.

```
echo "export SSL_CERT_FILE=<Path to Certificate>/ZscalerRootCA.pem" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

which I got from
https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trusted-store#curl-SSL_CERT_FILE
They have more commands for other applications

If you use any other shells, make sure to change `.bashrc` to the directory of the configuration of that file. In my case I use fish, so I replaced `$HOME/.bashrc` with `$HOME/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
echo "export SSL_CERT_FILE=<Path to Certificate>/ZscalerRootCA.pem" >> $HOME/.config/fish/config.fish
```

After adding the certificate, make sure to reload the shell. In my case, I ran using instructions from [jeffmcneil](https://jeffmcneill.com/path-bash-shell-fish-shell/)

```
source ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

for bash, you would want to run
`source ~/.bashrc`
or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/16150356

Comment: This worked for me. I used it in wsl2 with ubuntu. I got my pem file from admin

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution for Windows OS

After your Zscaler root cert is installed in the Windows trust root store, just install [pip-system-certs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/) the successor to [python-certifi-win32](https://pypi.org/project/python-certifi-win32/) which is no longer maintained. Both packages are available from either pypi or conda-forge, so use either `pip`, `conda`, or `mamba` to install pip-system-certs into every Python environment in which you use the Requests package. The pip-system-certs package patches certifi at runtime to use the Windows trusted root store. This solves the issue for the requests package without resorting to setting `$REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` and/or editing your `cacert.pem` files.

#### Solution for Ubuntu

Copy the Zscaler root certificate file, it must have `.crt` ending and be in PEM format, to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and use `sudo update-ca-certificates` to update your `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` file. However, even then, `pip-system-certs` doesn't quite seem to work, so add `export $REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to your `.profile` and restart your shell.

For more information read the following:

- [Requests uses the certifi CA Certificate bundle](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ca-certificates)
- [Certifi, a "carefully curated" bundle of CA certs](https://certifiio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [install CA certificate in Ubuntu trusted root store](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store)
- [Zscaler help, adding custom certificate root stores](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trust-store)
- [installing custom root stores](https://community.zscaler.com/t/installing-tls-ssl-root-certificates-to-non-standard-environments/7261)

*WARNING: I do **not** recommend editing any Python `cacert.pem` files. Note that they are all linked so editing one edits all, and your mamba/conda solver may complain that your package cache is invalid because the file size changed due to your edits. Look in each environments `ssl/` folder including base env, and in the base env's `pkgs/ca-certificates-<date>` files. On Windows OS, `cacert.pem` is in `Library\ssl` instead of `ssl/`. Finally the `cacert.pem` file will be overwritten if/when you install or update the Python certifi package, so editing it is really **not** the ideal solution. A better alternative would be to put your Zscaler root cert in a new `ssl/` folder in your home directory and set `$REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` to that location. If your company is using Zscaler, then I think it's the only root cert you need.*